# How to make SwiftUI WebView dynamically load an URL?

Tags: swift, swiftui, webview

I added this code to be able to use WebView in SwiftUI:

```
extension WKWebView {
    func load(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            load(request)
        }
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var url: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(url)
    }
}
```

however I need to navigate to an URL when a button is clicked.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showLoginForm: Bool = true
    ...    
    var webView = WebView(url: "https://www.google.com")
    ...
    var body: some View {
        if showLoginForm {
            ...
            Button(action: {
                showLoginForm = false
                webView.url = "https://www.example.com/go/1"
            }) { ... }
        } else {
            webView
        }
    }
}
```

but the `webView` stays on the initial page

Comment: Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61059318/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65465719/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071151/12299030 .. just search more by `WKWebView` here

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to change the `URL` outside of your webview, you don't make the `@State` inside of the webview itself.
Remember, state means that it's the **source of truth**, and usually it must be marked as `private`.

So `@State` is not meant to be changed from outside.

Moreover, changing the url by doing `webView.url = "https://www.example.com/go/1"` doesn't re-render.

I would change your implementation to something like

```swift
extension WKWebView {
    func load(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            load(request)
        }
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(url)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showLoginForm: Bool = true
    @State private var url = "https://www.google.com"

    var body: some View {
        if showLoginForm {
            Button(action: {
                showLoginForm = false
                url = "https://www.example.com/go/1"
            }) { Text("Try!") }
        } else {
            WebView(url: url)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `url` now belongs to the view that can change it.
Changing that value, will re-render the webview, which now has the correct url.

Comment: Is it possible to use `@ObservedObject` to do this? I am currently dealing with a situation where the URL _needs_ to be passed in from another View.