# How do I refresh a WKWebView via @StateObject stored in another class after altering a property on an @ObservedObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a basic model like this"

```
public final class WebSite: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var URL: String
    // Let us please assume that this will be a valid URL
}
```

And a webview. It uses the site url to render a `UIViewRepresentable` (my site view must be a class bc of the `WKWebView` protocol):

```
class WebSiteWebView: WKWebView {
    @ObservedObject
    var webSite: WebSite

    init() { /* initialization. Not relevant here*/ }

    loadUrl(url: String) {
        self.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    render() -> some View {
        let representable = WebSiteWebView.Representable(webView: self)
        
        do {
            try representable.webView.loadUrl(url: self.webSite.url)
        } catch { ... }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a parent ContentView as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var webSite: WebSite = WebSite(URL: "stackoverflow.com")

    var body: some View {
        WebSiteView(webSite: webSite)
    }
}
```

and a `WebSiteView` that displays a web view:

```
struct WebSiteView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var webSite: WebSite
    
    var body: some View {
        let webView: WebSiteWebView = WebView(webSite: webSite)

        VStack {
            webView.render()

            Button("Switch URL") {
                webSite.URL = "google.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `UIViewRepresentable` impl for completeness

```
extension WebSiteWebView {
    struct Representable: UIViewRepresentable {
        let webView: WebSiteWebView

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WebSiteWebView {
            self.webView
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: WebSiteWebView, context: Context) {}
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, this is what's going on:

1. The parent ContentView initializes a `@StateObject` that contains a published `String` named `URL`.
2. The ContentView has a child view named `WebSiteView` that takes the web site class as an `@ObservedObject`
3. That child view loads the `URL` from the `@ObservedObject`
4. That child view also has a button that changes the `URL`

I would expect that after the button is pressed, the `WebSiteView` would re-render, since it declares the `webSite` as an `@ObservedObject`. And, it does (technically). `webView.render()` is called with the new `URL` but the `WKWebView` does not refresh. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers only work in SwiftUI views, they won’t work as you expect in a UIKit class

Comment: The first thing that catches the eye is the usage of `@ObservedObject` inside your `WebSiteWebView`. This won´t work the way you may think.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions on what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Holding on to the view and calling render like it is a regular variable is also unorthodox. I doubt that works as you expect. Try the SwiftUI tutorials it is obvious you have some programming background but SwiftUI is not like other frameworks.

Comment: It turns out that `render()` actually is called when the `webSite.URL` is set, however the `WKWebView` is not reloading. Any thoughts as to why that might be happening?

Comment: `let webView: WebSiteWebView = WebView(webSite: webSite)` - this creates a different `WebSiteWebView` instance every time `body` is called, which can happen a lot of times. Likely you see `render` called on instances not yet added, or already removed, from the UI.

Comment: @Cristik agreed, it does create a new instance. But it also adds it to the View. If I understand correctly, SwiftUI will refresh the entire View tree when a change to an ObservedObject is made. And, that _does_ appear to be happening here. However, It just isn't reloading the web view.

Comment: SwiftUI is at liberty to call the body method as many times as it needs/wants. Creating heap-allocated data in the body is thus not advised, there's `@State`/`@StabeObject` for that, however those won't work for you.

Comment: And likely that's why you see unexpected results.

Comment: And as other's have noticed, you're using an `@ObservedObject` outside of a SwiftUI view, if you want to make it work as expected, you'll need to make some adjustments.

Comment: Interesting point. I don't know what adjustments to make here. I need to be able to dynamically reload the webview when a user clicks a button. Maybe the solution is to tear the existing webview down and render a new one? Or something else? Please, if you have ideas, let me know.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69855076/1974224) post, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

things are a bit backwards, it needs to be like this:

```
    struct WebSiteWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
        let url: URL

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
            WKWebView()
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
            if uiView.url != url {
                uiView.load(url)
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically the `WebSiteWebView` struct can be recreated many times and your job is to update the `WKWebView` object with any change to the properties. `updateUIView` is called the first time and also any time the `url` changes.

Comment: Please read my question, `WebSiteWebView` must be a class. `UIViewRepresentable` must be a value object (`struct`). Your solution will not work for my use case.